# Is there any way to check column by column using REGEX?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a doubt about regex. I am using regex to check the pattern of the data of a column but I am doing the process row by row which consumes a lot of time. Is there any way to do column by column?

My code:

```
df =
  a        b    c
0 rt-0000  abc  1
1 rt-0000  vb   2
2 rt-1234  abc  3
3 RT-1234  op   4
4 rt-123   oip  5

format = 'rt-\d\d\d\d'
wrong_pattern = []
regex = re.compile(format) 
for index, row in df[key].iteritems():
           if regex.search(str(row)) == None:
                 wrong_pattern.append(index)
                 wrong_df= df.loc[wrong_pattern]
                 correct_df=df.drop(wrong_pattern)
```

output:

```
wrong_df:
  a        b    c
3 RT-1234  op   4
4 rt-123   oip  5

correct_df:
  a        b    c
0 rt-0000  abc  1
1 rt-0000  vb   2
2 rt-1234  abc  3
```

Though I am getting the correct output. I would like to know if this can be done using only a column. As row by row takes a loot of time to get processed.

Comment: Why are compiling (`regex = re.compile(format)`) for each row, despite `format` does not change, rather than compiling before loop start?

Comment: @Daweo ya that must be outside the loop.

Comment: @Daweo But my problem is. Is there any better way where we can check the pattern by column by column. Append non-matched rows into separate df and matched into separate df#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract records for which pattern match and does not match into separate `DataFrame`s consider following simple example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A1','A2','B1','B2','C1','C2'],'value':[100,200,300,400,500,600]})
df_c = df[df.name.str.match(r'C.+')]
df_notc = df[~df.name.str.match(r'C.+')]
print("C")
print(df_c)
print("NOT C")
print(df_notc)
```

output

```
C
  name  value
4   C1    500
5   C2    600
NOT C
  name  value
0   A1    100
1   A2    200
2   B1    300
3   B2    400
```